# Can't create managed solution in CRM 2011 after importing CRM 4.0 Org

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am upgrading a CRM 4.0 org to a CRM 2011 org. I started the process by importing the CRM 4.0 org into the CRM 2011 org. It seems that I am now unable to create a managed solution from what I have imported. It currently has my customizations all under the default/active solution, and I am only able to export them as an unmanaged solution. Then when I import this unmanaged solution, it imports all of the customizations into the default/active solution again. Is there any way to create a managed solution out of these changes? Or is my only option to manually re-create all the customizations in a new unmanaged solution and export is as a managed solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are getting confused about what the default solution is.  You can only import/export the default solution in an unmanaged state because it is the library of all customizations that have been done to a CRM Organization - not a traditional "solution" that contains specific changes that you select.

You have complete control over what items go into a managed or unmanaged solution.  Just set up a solution and when you are exporting it, select to export it as managed (only the default solution wont allow you to do this).  To be clear - you don't have to recreate any of the customizations, you just have to "Add Existing" within the solution that will eventually become your unmanaged solutions and then within the Add Existing window, select all.